# Connection refused by AMAVISD-NEW

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, amavis, clamav

I found here many information to set a AWS server on my own.

I installed the DKIM patch and it's work great, but now I can't send mails.
I had already problems sending mails, but now are deeper.
Some mails was sent and I tested my DKIM sign, but now I don't know what happened...

ISPConfig version is 3.0.5.4p9 with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

You can see mail.log here:

```
May  1 20:55:17 dingalin postfix/smtpd[3235]: connect from unknown[206.132.109.65]
May  1 20:55:18 dingalin postfix/smtpd[3235]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from unknown[206.132.109.65]: <my@domain.org>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<my@domain.org> to=<my@destiny.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[127.0.0.1]>
May  1 20:55:18 dingalin postfix/smtpd[3235]: A7CD1606D7: client=unknown[206.132.109.65], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=my@domain.org
May  1 20:55:29 dingalin dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<my@domain.org>, method=PLAIN, rip=206.132.109.65, lip=172.31.20.52, mpid=3273, TLS, session=<gHdZnNAxmgDOhG1B>
May  1 20:55:34 dingalin postfix/cleanup[3271]: A7CD1606D7: message-id=<2cf6e686-8c98-0b9c-37e4-a0fdc5b16573@donamos.org>
May  1 20:55:34 dingalin postfix/qmgr[2357]: A7CD1606D7: from=<my@domain.org>, size=12483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  1 20:55:34 dingalin postfix/qmgr[2357]: warning: connect to transport private/amavis: Connection refused
May  1 20:55:34 dingalin postfix/error[3274]: A7CD1606D7: to=<my@destiny.com>, relay=none, delay=17, delays=16/0/0/0, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)
May  1 20:55:36 dingalin postfix/smtpd[3235]: disconnect from unknown[206.132.109.65]
```

I already read many tutorials and forums with the same problem but I still stopped on that.

Obviously the problem is "warning: connect to transport private/amavis: Connection refused"

I have the same results from Thunderbird and SquirrelMail.
The process completed succesfully, without errors, but the e.mail never leaves the queue

My /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#  -o cleanup_service_name=subcleanup
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d vmail ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop} ${sender}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}

smtp-amavis     unix    -       -       -       -       2       smtp
        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
        -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
        -o max_use=20

subcleanup unix n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
    -o header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks

127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
        -o content_filter=
        -o local_recipient_maps=
        -o relay_recipient_maps=
        -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
        -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
        -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
        -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
        -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
        -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
        -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
        -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
        -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks

127.0.0.1:10027 inet    n       -       n       -       -       smtpd

    -o content_filter=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
    -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o milter_default_action=accept
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

My /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
mydomain = dingalin.com

biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
# myhostname = ip-172-31-20-52.sa-east-1.compute.internal ESTA JODE
#myhostname = dingalin.com
myhostname = mail.dingalin.com
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
#mydestination = $myhostname, /etc/postfix/virtual/domains
#mydestination = localhost
# mydestination = dingalin.com ESTA NO FUNCIONA
# mydestination = mail.dingalin.com
relayhost =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
#virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual/addresses
#virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
owner_request_special = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings

# DKIM
# --------------------------------------
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
#smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:12768
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
#message_size_limit = 0
#mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
message_size_limit = 0[/CODE]

netstat -tap
[CODE]Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 localhost:10027         *:*                     LISTEN      2352/master
tcp        0      0 *:submission            *:*                     LISTEN      2352/master
tcp        0      0 localhost:11211         *:*                     LISTEN      2199/memcached
tcp        0      0 *:pop3                  *:*                     LISTEN      1032/dovecot
tcp        0      0 *:imap2                 *:*                     LISTEN      1032/dovecot
tcp        0      0 localhost:spamd         *:*                     LISTEN      1179/spamd.pid
tcp        0      0 *:urd                   *:*                     LISTEN      2352/master
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN      2376/pure-ftpd (SER
tcp        0      0 172.31.20.52:domain     *:*                     LISTEN      1098/named
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        *:*                     LISTEN      1098/named
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      1036/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN      2352/master
tcp        0      0 localhost:953           *:*                     LISTEN      1098/named
tcp        0      0 localhost:8891          *:*                     LISTEN      2216/opendkim
tcp        0      0 *:imaps                 *:*                     LISTEN      1032/dovecot
tcp        0      0 *:pop3s                 *:*                     LISTEN      1032/dovecot
tcp        0      0 localhost:10024         *:*                     LISTEN      1173/amavisd-new (m
tcp        0      0 localhost:10025         *:*                     LISTEN      2352/master
tcp        0      0 localhost:10026         *:*                     LISTEN      1173/amavisd-new (m
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN      1106/mysqld
tcp        0      0 172.31.20.52:imap2      206.132.109.65:49337    ESTABLISHED 2784/imap-login
tcp        0      0 172.31.20.52:imap2      206.132.109.65:50213    ESTABLISHED 3585/imap-login
tcp        0      0 172.31.20.52:imap2      206.132.109.65:50450    ESTABLISHED 3934/imap-login
tcp        0      0 172.31.20.52:ssh        206.132.109.65:65344    ESTABLISHED 2457/sshd: ubuntu [
tcp        0      0 172.31.20.52:imap2      206.132.109.65:49448    ESTABLISHED 2993/imap-login
tcp        0    464 172.31.20.52:ssh        206.132.109.65:50451    ESTABLISHED 3951/sshd: ubuntu [
tcp        0      0 172.31.20.52:imap2      206.132.109.65:49362    ESTABLISHED 2827/imap-login
tcp6       0      0 [::]:submission         [::]:*                  LISTEN      2352/master
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3               [::]:*                  LISTEN      1032/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imap2              [::]:*                  LISTEN      1032/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:spamd     [::]:*                  LISTEN      1179/spamd.pid
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN      2565/apache2
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN      2565/apache2
tcp6       0      0 [::]:tproxy             [::]:*                  LISTEN      2565/apache2
tcp6       0      0 [::]:urd                [::]:*                  LISTEN      2352/master
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ftp                [::]:*                  LISTEN      2376/pure-ftpd (SER
tcp6       0      0 [::]:domain             [::]:*                  LISTEN      1098/named
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      1036/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:smtp               [::]:*                  LISTEN      2352/master
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:953       [::]:*                  LISTEN      1098/named
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN      2565/apache2
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imaps              [::]:*                  LISTEN      1032/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3s              [::]:*                  LISTEN      1032/dovecot
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a typo here. Looks at the error message

```
warning: connect to transport private/amavis: Connection refused
```

You instruct postfix to send email via transport `amavis`, but in your `master.cf`, you define transport `smtp-amavis`

```
smtp-amavis unix  -    -     -    -   2 smtp
    ...
```

Check if you have define transport `amavis` somewhere else in your config. **For example** in your `main.cf`

```
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

or in the other maps file in directory `/etc/postfix`.